# What could be the possible reasons for webpack-dev-server's hot reload not functioning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

In my React project, when I run the command "npm start" or "yarn start" with the webpack-dev-server configured to use hot reload (--hot flag), I encounter the following error: [error message here]. Can you please help me troubleshoot this issue?

### My file structure:

**package.json:**

```
  {
    "name": "reactapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
    },
    "author": "Sheharzad",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "react": "^16.4.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
        "webpack": "^4.17.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.6"
    }
  }
```

**App.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}
export default App;
```

**main.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: please your dev build script in package.json

Answer (score 1):

Listen you haven't added **webpack cli** package which accepts `--hot` flag. Try after adding this package. It should work. Let me know If it doesn't help.

**EDITED:** `"start" : "webpack-dev-server --mode development --config webpack.config.js --open --hot:`

make sure you have webpack config in your root folder and restart your dev server.

Comment: "npm install wepback cli" is added so it does not work

Comment: I have made changes in start script

Comment: WAIT show your package.json. There's something wrong with webpack CLI installation

Comment: They all should be your dev dependencies. please make sure.